# c# two JObjects one foreach

Tags: c#, json, linq

I have response in JSON format. For grades:

```
string grade_json = GetResponse(sign(grade_url));
var grade = JObject.Parse(grade_json).SelectTokens("['course_units_grades'].*.*.['value_symbol']");
```

response

```
4
3
3,5
5
pass
...
```

and for courses:

```
string course_json = GetResponse(sign(courses_url));
var course_title = JObject.Parse(course_json).SelectTokens("['course_editions'].*.[*].['course_name'].['en']");
```

response:

```
    Preparation for bachelor exam
    Work experience
    OHS training
    ...
```

But the thing is that first two grades in a response are for first course (lecture and class), second two grades are for second course and so on, like this:

```
    4 - Preparation for bachelor exam (Lecture grade)
    3 - Preparation for bachelor exam (class grade)
    3,5 - Work experience (Lecture grade)
    5 - Work experience (class grade)
    pass - OHS training (this is the exception, It has just one not-number value)
    ...
```

so when I've tried to use `el.A.next` or `el.A.ElementAt<>` here:

```
                    foreach (var el in grade.Zip(course_title, (a, b) => new { A = a, B = b }))
                    {
                         SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Grades (lecture_grade, class_grade, course_title) Values ('" + el.A + "','" + el.A + "','" + el.B + "')", myConnection);
                         myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
```

it didn't work. To make it complicated the `OHS training` and not number value related with it, was the last nail in the coffin. Feel like I'm stuck here. I would really appreciate any help you could give me

**EDITED:**

Yes, there are common id values. These are first two courses in original response:

```
{
"course_editions": {
"2014/SL": [
  {
    "course_id": "06-DEGZLI0",
    "term_id": "2014/SL",
    "course_name": {
      "en": "Preparation for bachelor exam",
    }
  },
  {
    "course_id": "06-DPRALW0",
    "term_id": "2014/SL",
    "course_name": {
      "en": "Work experience",
    }
  },
  {
```

To get a grade I need to build a URL with two fields/(url parameters) that are required: `course_id` and `term_id`, so f.e. for first course I will get this response(yes, I've missed that there are courses with just one grade):

```
{
  "course_units_grades": {
    "159715": {
      "1": {
        "value_symbol": "4",
        "exam_session_number": 1,
        "exam_id": 198172,
        "value_description": {
          "en": "good",
        }
      },
      "2": null
    }
  },
  "course_grades": null
}
```

So, yes there are common id values.

Comment: Looks like you should select a few more tokens to be able to simply group-join the responses. I mean, don't the grades and courses have some common Id value?

Comment: what is "159715" and what is "1", "2" of "course unit grades"?  What is your common id value(s) that relates a course to a course grade?  I would expect something like "course_id" and "term_id" to show in course grades response which doesn't look like it from your examples.